# Detectar coincidencias en multiples archivos con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola soy nuevo programando y he estado experimentando haciendo algunos scripts que me han ayudado mucho en mi trabajo, me gustaría en este caso poder avanzar más con un script pero no encuentro manera de lograr lo que quiero hacer.

Mi script es:

```
with open('D:/Python/detectar_coincidencias/Emails/00AA34B3078446DB90C489BAFF37B611.MAI', 'r') as file1:
    with open('D:/Python/detectar_coincidencias/Emails/0AFA934556264ABFA0FC901F12786D29.MAI', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Esto solo me ayuda a ver dos archivos en una sola carpeta pero me gustaría que detecte la cantidad de archivos con extension .MAI que hay en esta carpeta y poder comparar estos de alguna manera y escribir las coincidencias encontradas en otro archivo nuevo.

Podrán ayudarme dándome algunas pistas o algunas soluciónes de como lograrlo?

Saludos y desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cual es tu criterio de comparacion?

Comment: quieres buscar coincidencias por línea a línea, palabra por palabra, o que coincidan completamante?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conservando tu criterio de comparación ya que no específicas más, esta es mi solución:

```
import os
import glob
import filecmp

path = 'directorio de los archivos'
extension = '*.txt'

def comparar_linea(file1, file2):
    data1 = [line.strip() for line in file1.readlines()]
    data2 = [line.strip() for line in file2.readlines()]
    same = set(data1).intersection(data2)
    return same

def buscarCoincidencias(path, extension):
    with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
        os.chdir(path)
        files = glob.glob(extension)
        for i in range(len(files)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(files)):
                with open(files[i]) as file1:
                    with open(files[j], 'r') as file2:
                        same = comparar_linea(file1, file2)
                        file_out.write(files[i] + "-"+ files[j] + ": "+str(same)+"\n")


buscarCoincidencias(path, extension)
```

En mi caso tengo:

test.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

test1.txt

```
3
4
5
6
```

test2.txt

```
2
2
3
3
```

some_output_file.txt:

```
test2.txt-test1.txt: {'3'}
test2.txt-test.txt: {'3', '2'}
test1.txt-test.txt: {'5', '4', '3'}
```

Comment: Wow, esta fue el código que más me ha ayudado, encontré un error en la ante última linea

Comment: @HugoLesta cual es el error?

Comment: Wow, esta fue el código que más me ha ayudado, encontré un error en la ante última linea

file_out.write(files[i] + "-"+ files[j] z+ ": "+str(same)+"\n")

Le quité la z para que funcione, pero me ha traído beunos resultados, he comprobado que para que sea menos pesado el escaneo pude añadir lo siguiente: same.discard('\n') luego de declarar la variable same. Gracias!

Comment: @HugoLesta se me paso la z cuando copie el código:P

Comment: he presionado sobre la V de correcto, espero que te sirva y muchas gracias por tu ayuda y a todos los  demás que me han ayudado también!

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener todos los ficheros con una determinada extensión puedes usar varios métodos. Una opción es usar [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdirglob.glob()) para listar todos los archivos y luego filtrar por el atributo `endswith`. Otra opción es usar [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html).

En cuanto a compararlos, depende de lo que quieras hacer. Si lo que quieres es obtener las **lineas que están presentes en todos los ficheros** sin excepción puedes usar `set.interesection` como haces en tu ejemplo. Si deseas comparar por parejas o otra cosa deberías especificar un poco más como quieres realizar la comparación para poderte ayudar mejor.

Te dejo un ejemplo con comentarios a ver si es lo que deseas:

```
import glob
import os


ruta = 'D:/Python/detectar_coincidencias/Emails'
os.chdir(ruta)

# Creamos un generador para abrir todos los archivos con extensión .MAI de la ruta
open_files = (open(file, 'r') for file in glob.glob("*.MAI"))

# Comparamos todos los archivos usando set.intersection().
## Esto nos retornará un conjuntos con las lineas PRESENTES en TODOS los archivos
same = set.intersection(*map(set, open_files))
same.discard('\n')

#Cerramos todos los archivos abiertos:
for f in open_files:
    f.close()

#Abrimos el archivo de destino y guardamos el contenido de la comparacion:
with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
for line in same:
    file_out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola una posible solución seria esta

```
import os
import filecmp

def filtrarCoincidencias(ruta,extension):
    files=[ x for x in os.listdir(ruta) if x.endswith(extension)]
    coincidencias=[]

    for i,f1 in enumerate(files):
        for j,f2 in enumerate(files):
            if(j>i):
                if(filecmp.cmp(ruta+f1,ruta+f2)):
                    coincidencias.append((f1,f2))
    return coincidencias


for tupla in filtrarCoincidencias("/home/crack81/Escritorio/folder/",".MAI"):
    print(tupla)
```

A la función filtrarCondidencias le pasas la ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo y la extensión de los ficheros que quieres comparar, te devuleve una lista de tuplas con los nombres de los ficheros que coincidan.
Solo faltaría que tu escribas las coincidencias en otro fichero.

Comment: Estas repitiendo comparaciones, por ejemplo vas a compara el archivo "l" con "m" en una primera iteración, pero uego vas a comparar el archivo "m" con "l"

Comment: Además filecmp.cmp retorna True si el contenido es identico, y False si existe una parcial coincidencia

Comment: Tienes razon yo entendi que solo compararia los ficheros en concreto y no parcialmente y lo primero que has mencionando basta con agregar en el if un j> i y listo algo asi  if(i!=j and  j>i):

Comment: Exacto @Rene, todos los comentarios son para mejorar la respuesta, si puedes colocar la modificación sería genial

Comment: @eyllanesc si ahí lo tienes editado.

Comment: esto **i!=j and  j>i** se puede remplazar solo con **j>i**

Comment: @eyllanesc corregido.